# Tensor summation help - einstein notation

Tags: differential-geometry

If $(x)^2 = x_u x^u$  then what is $x^4$ ?

I have thought about

$(x)^4 = x_{vu} x^{vu}$ 
and
$(x)^4 = x_{uu} x^{uu}$ 
But I am honestly not sure...

Comment: Isn't it simply $(x^2)^2$ since $x^2$ is scalar ? (I'm reaaaaaally not sure about this)

Comment: I have thought about it but too, I dont know how I would write it out properly

Comment: I would have written it $(x_ux^u)^2$. If $x$ is a vector, I don't see any other way to write it.

Comment: Horrible notation from the outset!

Comment: Is that what retired university lecturers do on their free time? Come complain about notation without any hints of help? nice life

Comment: @AlexSanteri Did you get an answer ?